# Display Registered Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Another question. I have a custom post type called "Articles" Within that I have registered some taxonomies using register_taxonomy called "Article Topics" So my client would pop over to Articles, put in a new article, fill out the publisher, and link to where its published, choose the topic its about...all good.

Except: How do i get those "topics" to display in the sidebar. How do i make a sub-nav out of registered taxonomies? Something like this:

```
<?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
```

Is this even a good idea? Or should I just say to hell with it, and go back to categories, and ditch the custom post type?

Thanks.

Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the codex page for [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'article_topics' );
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

For the taxonomy terms assigned to individual posts, [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) also accepts a `taxonomy` argument.

Comment: Oh cool! This is my first time using custom post types, so I had no idea that call was tied to them. Now I know. Sorry for the noob question. But thanks. :)

Comment: ...any chance that also works with the likes of the_category() within the loop or something similar? ...ie: showing the topics covered in that article. Codex says no, currently hunting around.

Comment: [`get_the_term_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list): `echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'article_topics', '', ', ', '' ); `